# JScover to get coverage report of UI project running on linux environment

Tags: code-coverage

I would like to use JScover to check code coverage for my javascript changes.
I needed some guidance on how to proceed.
I'm able to run the example application.
But not my project.

The UI project runs in linux server with dependency on other back-end projects(sending request and receiving response) that uses C++ and runs in default port.

As far as I understand, it is coz of change in port number.
Please let me know if there is any way to run JScover without changing port number.
Or if there is a way to get coverage report even with change in port number.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to measure JavaScript coverage as part of your application. In that case you don't run JSCover in web-server mode, as that is only for running test suites like Jasmine, QUnit, Mocha, etc...

Try running JSCover in file-system mode, that is, instrument your JavaScript files, then deploy them as part of your application. The basic approach is:

1. Instrument the JavaScript
2. Package your application with the instrumented JavaScript
3. Run your tests
4. Extract and save the coverage data to jscoverage.json
5. Save the report files as needed

The is a working example of this approach at https://github.com/tntim96/JSCover/tree/master/examples/localStorage-file-system

JSCover also has a proxy mode which may work for your needs, but SSL is not supported. Going with the file-instrumentation is the most robust approach.